# Python cx_Freeze import _tkinter and ImportError: DLL load failed %1 is not a valid win32 application ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

cx_Freeze import _tkinter #if this fails your python may not be configurated for Tk.. ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application

Hi! I created a word guessing/memorizing language practice program in tkinter, and i wanted to convert it to an executable app but i get errors again and again... I tried at least 10-15 different ways but it is still same. So i googled all the similar topics and tried every single suggestion but they did not work for me. I tried pyinstaller as well. It does not give an error but also it does not run the executed app either. When i click on the app.exe, black CMD screen appears then disappears and it creates the csv file to save the words. So i changed to cx_Freeze but it does not work either.

What have i tried?

For pyinstaller:
I converted my app.py to app.exe by using pyinstaller -F app.py and pyinstaller app.py, but none of them worked.
For cx_Freeze
1- I tried my old setup.py (which worked to convert my all games to .exe) but it did not work on this, i guess it is about tkinter. Because my games were written with pygame, i did not use tkinter for anything.
2 -I tried at least 10 different setup files shared by you guys on stackoverflow and other websites. But they did not work either.
3- I tried to set environment
4- I tried to specify environment
5- I copied tcl86t.dll and tk86t.dll files from the python dlls to my app directory and added them as included files in the setup.py
6- I deleted 64bit version and i only have 32bit version of python3.7
and more and more...

So this is my current setup.py

```
import sys,os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\Python37\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\Python37\tcl\tk8.6"

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"],"includes":["tkinter"],"include_files": []}


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "App",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base)]
)
```

I use Windows7 64bit and Python 3.7.1 32bit and 3.7.0 64bit

So what should i do? I am stuck here. I really gave up and asking a new question on here. Please help me guys.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. ) what cx_Freeze version are you using? try to update to 6.2. It solved many of my problems. 2.) Try pyinstaller with console and run your app from CMD console, it will give you an error message.

Comment: i updated cx_Freeze to 6.2 but now a CMD screen appears and then it creates "words.csv" file and then the CMD screen disappears. Also same for pyinstaller. No error, but same thing. I did run my app on CMD, it is running for a couple of seconds, creates "words.csv" file and then the CMD screen disappears.